# Is it possible to direct output of map-reduce to multiple Map files?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, nutch

**Here is the use case:**

I have a nutch crawldb (its a hadoop map file) containing data about urls which includes its status as visited and not-visited. I want to split it into 2 crawldb (map files) based on the status of the urls.

Till now i tried using [MultipleOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html) but I read that it will work for sequence files or text files and NOT map files.

(FYI: i am using hadoop v20.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look instead at [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputs.html), you'll have to write a custom reducer to call the MultipleOutputs.getCollector() method for each type, there's example usage in the javadocs.

**In your job configuration:**

```
 MultipleOutputs.addMultiNamedOutput(conf, "map",
   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapFileOutputFormat.class,
   LongWritable.class, Text.class);
```

Comment: will it work for map files ? the examples there only highlight sequence files or text files

Comment: Yes any output format will work, updated with example job conf code